# getting empty data from an array in angular

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I'm trying to display some data using datatable. I have data stored in an array and I'm able to console those values after fetching them but when i console it in the datatable it shows an empty array. How do I resolve this?

> **component.ts**

```
user_data:any= [];

constructor(private http:Http, private Authentication:AuthService) {}

getUsersFromServices():void{
this.Authentication.fetch_userdata().subscribe(
  (data) =>{ 
    this.user_data = data;  
    console.log(this.user_data); //able to console the values here
  },err =>{
    console.log(err);
  }
 )
}

dataTable(){
console.log(this.user_data); //getting an empty array here
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 4,
  columnDefs:[{
    targets:[0,1,2,3,4],
    orderable:false
  }],
  data:this.user_data,
  columns:[
    {
      title:'id',
      data:'user.id'
    },
    {
      title:'First Name',
      data:'user.first_name'
    },
    {
      title:'Last Name',
      data:'user.last_name'
    },
    {
      title:'Email',
      data:'user.email'
    },
    {
      title:'Role',
      data:'role'
    }
  ]
};
}


ngOnInit(): void {
this.getUsersFromServices();
this.dataTable();
}
```

[image: data after fetching]

[image: data while consoling in the datatable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the **`dataTable()`** function once you get the data within your subscribe, otherwise you are trying to access before the data being recieved from the request, change it as follows,

```
this.Authentication.fetch_userdata().subscribe(
  (data) =>{ 
    this.user_data = data;  
    console.log(this.user_data); //able to console the values here
    this.dataTable();
  },err =>{
    console.log(err);
  }
 )
}
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan Congratulation for cap.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
console.log(this.user_data); //able to console the values here
this.dataTable();
```

Call your method hear instead of call in `ngOnInit`